# How to allow a user permission to recycle an application pool in IIS 6?

Tags: permissions, iis-6, application-pool

Is it possible to give a (non admin) user permissions to recycle a specific application pool? This is specifically for IIS 6.

Comment: Do you mean a non-admin user who would be logged in to the server itself, or an end user connecting through a website?

Answer (score 2):

I found a kind of round about way to get this done, as I couldn't find a simple way either.  There may be some security concerns I've missed, so I would approach this with caution.  My scenario involved a trusted, non-malicious user who requested less access.

I created a batch file with the command to reset the app pool in IIS.  From there I created a single run scheduled task to run that batch file with an administrator user set up on the scheduled task.  I then gave the required user read,write,and  execute security permissions on that scheduled task.

I then gave the user read permission on c:\windows\tasks through the cacls command line utility.  This then let that user access the scheduled tasks in control panel.  From there, he could manually execute the scheduled task to reset the app pool.  It works since the scheduled task is running under admin privileges.

You'll want to make sure that the user doesn't have access to modify the batch file, otherwise, you've basically given them an admin command prompt.  If the scheduled task is modified, the password has to be reentered (at least on my server 2003 machine) so they can't just point the task to any executable.